# AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'scatter_add'

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition, cupy

When trying to run a model for spacy NER training with

> spacy.require_gpu()

I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a86608cac558> in <module>
      3 }
      4 start_time = time.time()
----> 5 train_model(data)

<ipython-input-2-10f04ac303a6> in train_model(train_data)
     82     other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
     83     with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
---> 84         optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
     85         for itn in range(1):
     86             print("Starting iteration " + str(itn))

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in begin_training(self, get_gold_tuples, sgd, component_cfg, **cfg)
    623                 kwargs = component_cfg.get(name, {})
    624                 kwargs.update(cfg)
--> 625                 proc.begin_training(
    626                     get_gold_tuples,
    627                     pipeline=self.pipeline,

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.begin_training()

_parser_model.pyx in spacy.syntax._parser_model.ParserModel.begin_training()

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\thinc\check.py in checked_function(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
    154                     raise ExpectedTypeError(check, ["Callable"])
    155                 check(arg_id, fix_args, kwargs)
--> 156         return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    157 
    158     def arg_check_adder(func):

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\thinc\neural\_classes\model.py in begin_training(self, train_X, train_y, **trainer_cfg)
    120     def begin_training(self, train_X, train_y=None, **trainer_cfg):
    121         for hook in self.on_data_hooks:
--> 122             hook(self, train_X, train_y)
    123         return self.Trainer(self, **trainer_cfg)
    124 

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\spacy\_ml.py in <lambda>(model, X, y)
    149 
    150 @describe.on_data(
--> 151     _set_dimensions_if_needed, lambda model, X, y: model.init_weights(model)
    152 )
    153 @describe.attributes(

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\spacy\_ml.py in init_weights(model)
    268         t_i = 0
    269         for t_i in range(t_max):
--> 270             acts1 = predict(ids, tokvecs)
    271             var = model.ops.xp.var(acts1)
    272             mean = model.ops.xp.mean(acts1)

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\spacy\_ml.py in predict(ids, tokvecs)
    254                 (hiddens.shape[0] * model.nF, model.nO * model.nP)
    255             )
--> 256             model.ops.scatter_add(vectors, ids.flatten(), hiddens)
    257             vectors = vectors.reshape((vectors.shape[0], model.nO, model.nP))
    258             vectors += model.b

ops.pyx in thinc.neural.ops.CupyOps.scatter_add()

c:\users\aventus\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    873         value = _deprecated_attrs.get(name)
    874         if value is None:
--> 875             raise AttributeError(
    876                 f"module 'cupy' has no attribute {name!r}")
    877         attr, eq_attr = value

AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'scatter_add'
```

The data used for training the model is annotation for spacy NER.

When running spacy.require_gpu() got this:

```
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import spacy
>>>spacy.require_gpu()
True
```

- Os - Windows 10
- Python 3.8
- spacy 2.2.4
- cupy 9.0.0
- Nvidia Driver Version: 466.11
- CUDA Version: 11.1
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660Ti

How to get rid of this error? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like [an older version of cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/v2.2.0/reference/generated/cupy.scatter_add.html) used to have `cupy.scatter_add()`  The [latest version of cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupyx.scatter_add.html) seems to have it as `cupyx.scatter_add()`.  Switch to an older version of `cupy` (probably prior to 8.0) or else refactor the spacy NER code to use `cupyx.scatter_add()`.  You haven't given a link or anything to the spacy NER code, so I guess my suggestions stop there.

Comment: If you install spacy carefully using their instructions on a clean machine, you might get a proper version of cupy automagically.

Comment: i installed spacy in a virtual env using pip install -U spacy and installed cupy separately using pip install cupy-cuda111

Comment: That is likely what is causing this problem.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options to avoid this error:

- downgrade cupy to `cupy<8.0.0` (`pip install "cupy-cuda110<8.0.0"`)
- upgrade spacy to v2.3.5+

From the comments I don't know how you got spacy v2.2.4 from `pip install -U spacy`, but if you don't need that version in particular, upgrading to a version without this error is the easiest solution and newer versions are compatible with cupy v8.

If you definitely need spacy v2.2.4 (which requires `thinc==7.4.0`) and newer versions of cupy, you could apply this patch to thinc v7.4.0 and install from source:

https://github.com/explosion/thinc/pull/441/files#diff-742ac455f5934d8207f38852f68013706e9561e8832a5b7c5b85757fa295b5f0L47-R1090

See also: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5380

Comment: Thank you somuch for the reply. I got this version of spacy while installing the req.txt. However I was not able to configure the gpu correctly.